How to configure angular storybook for ngx-translate
I'm setting up an angular 18 UI library with standalone components. While configuring this for storybook 8 and the ngx-translate package, my json translation files (en.json, fr.json...) are not found.
My solution looks like:
projects/
  └── my-angular-library/
    ├── src/
    │   ├── lib/
    │   ├── assets/
    │   │   └── i18n/
    │   │       ├── en.json
    │   │       ├── fr.json
    │   │       └── ...
    │   └── public-api.ts
    └── ...

My  translate-config.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      defaultLanguage: 'en'
   })
  ],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class TranslateModuleConfig { }

The component where I use the translation pipe and import my config module. (Note the import of the translation pipe too)
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, TranslateModuleConfig, TranslatePipe],
  template: `<div>{{ 'greeting' | translate }}</div>`,
})
export class MyComponent {
  ...

This results in not finding my json language files. I tried to add some staticDirs: ['../public', '../static', '../src/assets'] in the main.ts file of Storybook, but that didn't work either.

Seems that you need to alter your angular.json file too. In the angular.json file, make sure to include the assets folder in the build configuration for your library:
"projects": {
  "my-angular-library": {
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        "options": {
          "assets": [
            "projects/my-angular-library/src/assets"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

